# Interpreting AWS RDS monitoring stats

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, cpu-usage

I have set up an RDS instance on AWS - running MariaDB. Our previous server was struggling at times, performance-wise, so I've gone for a fairly high-spec on the RDS install - a db.t3.2xlarge.

It offers 96 CPU credits per hour, but after a couple of days steady state, the stats suggest we're not get anywhere close to that.

[image: CPU Hourly credit use]

[image: CPU credit balance]

Can I interpret these as meaning my instance would cope on a lower spec?

Answer (score 0):

On AWS burstable instances exist so-called "Credit accrual limit" and it shows how many credits you can accumulate. if your instance offers 96 credits/h, the max amount of accumulated credits is 96*24=2304 Credits
More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html

Comment: That part I think I already understood. My question is about what that means for which instance type I choose: if, at 96 units per hour, I'm consistently accruing units, can I use a lower spec (lower units per hour) server and still get the performance I want?

Comment: From your first metric (based on 3 days), I think that db.t3.large(36credits/h) can be an option for try

Comment: That's what I think, but I don't know much about RDS, so wanted it confirmed by someone who knows a lot more...

Is it your guess, or you know for sure?